# Unbale to run python script from Ansible playbook

Tags: python, ansible

Ansible unbale to run python script from playbook
If I try to run the python script manually it works great.
But when I execute the script from Playbook it fails to recognize the variables.
And I get the following error:

```
TASK [Updates the current location for the test] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [root@10.0.141.17]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/root/Desktop/Under_Testing/10.0.124.90/PV/new_location.py", "delta": "0:00:00.046446", "end": "2020-09-02 14:07:31.527264", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-09-02 14:07:31.480818", "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/root/Desktop/Under_Testing/10.0.124.90/PV/new_location.py\", line 11, in <module>\n    fin = open(f\"{location}/Run/Ansible/Run/check_copy.sh\", \"rt\")\nFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/Run/Ansible/Run/check_copy.sh'", "stderr_lines": ["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/root/Desktop/Under_Testing/10.0.124.90/PV/new_location.py\", line 11, in <module>", "    fin = open(f\"{location}/Run/Ansible/Run/check_copy.sh\", \"rt\")", "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/Run/Ansible/Run/check_copy.sh'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
root@10.0.141.17           : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

this is my playbook:

```
- hosts: root@10.0.141.17
  become: true
  become_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: Copy files remote to remote
      copy:
       src: /LAB_Test/DATA/PV3/PV/
       dest: /root/Desktop/Under_Testing/10.0.124.90/PV/
       remote_src: yes
       owner: root
       group: root
       mode: 0777

    - name: Give permissions to core script
      file: dest=/root/Desktop/Under_Testing/10.0.124.90/PV/new_location.py mode=0777
    
    - name: Updates the current location for the test    
      shell: /root/Desktop/Under_Testing/10.0.124.90/PV/new_location.py
```

this is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""
This script for update the current location 
"""

import os, subprocess

location = os.getcwd()

fin = open(f"{location}/Run/Ansible/Run/check_copy.sh", "rt")
fin.close
with open(f"{location}/Run/Ansible/Run/check_copy_new.sh", "wt") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.replace("/root/Desktop/Under_Testing/PV", f"{location}"))

fin = open(f"{location}/Run/Ansible/Run/systeminfo.sh", "rt")
fin.close
with open(f"{location}/Run/Ansible/Run/systeminfo_new.sh", "wt") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line.replace("/root/Desktop/Under_Testing/PV", f"{location}"))
```

What could be the problem that the script can manually run without a problem but through the Playbook it fails?

Comment: does a file exist at `/root/Run/Ansible/Run/check_copy.sh`? because the error is telling you it does not

Comment: @gold_cy
I know, the problem starts after copying, the Python script should get the new location via the following command:
`location = os.getcwd ()`
But instead of setting the new location it sets the location `/ root /`
The location should be where the copy of the script is.
Again, if I run the script manually it works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script depends on the current dir during execution to set the `{location}` value.

By default, `shell` module executes commands in the home dir of the remote user (so in `/root/` in your case)

To change execution directory, use the [`chdir`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#parameter-chdir) parameter of `shell` module:

```yaml
    - name: Updates the current location for the test    
      shell: /root/Desktop/Under_Testing/10.0.124.90/PV/new_location.py
      args:
        chdir: /root/Desktop/Under_Testing/10.0.124.90/PV/  # From what I understand from your comment
```

Another solution would be to adapt your python script to not depend on the current dir, but instead the script dir (as it looks like it's the one you need):

```py
location = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

BTW, the "Give permissions to core script" task shouldn't be necessary as you already set the mode to `0777` during the copy task.